# Organization cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: Organization Name

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Organization cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: Organization Name
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient.ConnectToCrmWebService(String crmConnectionString)
```

My Connection  String  is

```
    <add name="CRM" connectionString="AuthType=AD;Url=domain:80/ashok; Domain=domain; Username=username; Password=pwd" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are passing the connection string, not the connection string name:

```
CrmServiceClient conn = new Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM"].ConnectionString);`
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this by adding `http://` in Url:

```
    <add name="CRM" connectionString="AuthType=AD;Url=http://domain:80/Configit; Domain=domain; Username=username; Password=pwd" />
```

It’s a simple miss.

Comment: That's really not suggested by the error, is it... it also worked